# Error when try to create a VIEW in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sequelpro

I like Sequel Pro to handle MySQL databases on Mac. Now I'm triying to create a view with this:

```
CREATE VIEW '_view_userlist' AS 
SELECT u.userid,u.fullname,u.username,e.userid,e.listid,e.title,e.status 
FROM users u 
LEFT OUTER JOIN list e ON e.userid=u.userid 
WHERE u.status=1 AND e.status=1 
ORDER BY e.title ASC
```

But I get this error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''_view_userlist' AS 
SELECT u.userid,u.fullname,u.username,e.userid,e.listid,e.t' at line 1
```

I'm no sure what really means. When a I try the request without the CREATE VIEW line all goes smooth.

I have MySQL 5.5.35. Any help o advise ??

Comment: Identifiers (the name of the view) must not be enclosed in single quotes. Single quotes are used to specify string literals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change

```
CREATE VIEW '_view_userlist' AS
```

as

```
CREATE VIEW `_view_userlist` AS
```

or

```
CREATE VIEW _view_userlist AS
```

**[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a78fc/1)**

Answer (score 2):

You should quote view name so the right syntax is

```
CREATE VIEW _view_userlist AS SELECT u.userid, ...
```

Also check the manual page http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-view.html